# Jupyter error: ImportError: cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal'

Tags: python, jupyter, protocol-buffers, importerror, mediapipe

I tried to import the package "mediapipe" to my jupyter environment but I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal' (C:\Users\R.F.Pravin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\__init__.py)
```

I need my code to perform the function of finding the stick points using this module but this doesn't work.